# Typescript : create object with nested level, key and values as variables

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, object, nested

I have an array of objects for each fields component of my react form, that i want to compile into an object with my form values.

```js
interface FormProps {
  name: string;
  subName?: string;
  value: undefined | string | number | boolean;
}

interface DatasProps {
  user: ProfileProps;
  friend: undefined | ProfileProps;
  phone: undefined | number;
  car: boolean;
}

interface ProfileProps {
  firstname: string;
  age: undefined | number;
  gender: 'male' | 'female';
}

const getDatas = (form: FormProps[]) => {
  const datas = {};

  // for (const elem of form) {
  // }

  return datas as DatasProps;
};

const form: FormProps[] = [
  {
    name: 'user',
    subName: 'firstname',
    value: 'Marc',
  },
  {
    name: 'user',
    subName: 'age',
    value: 32,
  },
  {
    name: 'user',
    subName: 'gender',
    value: 'male',
  },
  {
    name: 'friend',
    subName: 'firstname',
    value: 'Frank',
  },
  {
    name: 'friend',
    subName: 'gender',
    value: 'male',
  },
  {
    name: 'car',
    value: false,
  },
];

console.log(getDatas(form));
```

The expected result here, for `getDatas(form)`:

```json
{
  user: {
    firstname: 'Marc',
    age: 32,
    gender: 'male'
  },
  friend: {
    firstname: 'Frank',
    gender: 'male'
  },
  phone: undefined,
  car: false
}
```

I need to automate this because `DatasProps` and `FormProps` (`ProfileProps` depends on `FormProps`) can change.

I want to be able to apply `getDatas` to any form with one level of nested as we can see in `FormProps` :

- `name` as `key` in a loop: `array[key]`
- `subName` as `subKey`: `array[key][subKey]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) your array like this:

```
const getDatas = (form: FormProps[]): DatasProps=> {
  const datas = form.reduce((acc, field) => {
       if (!field.subName) {
           datas[field.name] = field.value
           continue;
       }

      if (!acc[field.name]) {
        acc[field.name] = {}
      }

      acc[field.name][field.subName] = field.value
      return acc
  }, {})
  
  return datas as DatasProps
};
```

or using a for loop :

```
const getDatas = (form: FormProps[]): DatasProps=> {
    const datas = {};
    for (const field of form) {
      if (!field.subName) {
        datas[field.name] = field.value
        continue;
      }

      if (!datas[field.name]) {
        datas[field.name] = {}
      }

      datas[field.name][field.subName] = field.value
    }
  
    return datas as DatasProps
};
```